# Issues trying my first hard development using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I can't find a good Zurb Foundation to "step by step wizard" so I decide to build my own (very simply and adapted to my business) so I created [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHJKW/4/) for testing purposes. The code works almost perfectly but has some issues:

1. if user click in any LI at `.product-wizard-bar` button steps aren't increment or decremented so in this case steps are lost and wizard get unusable.
2. finish button is never activated when I end the wizard at `product-create-step-5`

Can any give me a hand to solve this latest problems I'm having?

PS: some words are in spanish, apologies for that one, since I talk spanish by default ;)

Comment: Amigo your code is too long, it'd be better if you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ at least with the code to help you with the problem...

Comment: Here's a good sliding wizard/form: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/

Comment: Instead of apologies you could always translate identifiers to English and test that your new code sample behaves the same as the old one.

Comment: Also, obligatory comment: have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @darkajax takes your suggestion and created a jsFiddle take a look at main post once again

Comment: `ReferenceError: Routing is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

...ate-step-4 section").load(Routing.generate('get_product_details', {category_id: ...

/_display/ (line 42)
ReferenceError: Routing is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

...ct-create-step-5 section").load(Routing.generate('stock_new', {company_id: compa...

/_display/ (line 44)
ReferenceError: Routing is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

...ate-step-4 section").load(Routing.generate('get_product_details', {category_id: ...

/_display/ (line 65)` - seriously at least read the console first.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight this is relevant? Of course I'm using it on a Symfony2 project enviroment for this reason those issues but it move backward/fordward

Comment: oh and i think you should consider learning js b4 jquery, it might help a bit.

Comment: **`[Break On This Error]`** is relevant, yes.

Comment: I fixed the code at jsFiddle and @codingfreak what you mean with "without any ready script"? I made that code by myself getting help from users here

Comment: @Reynier I can't answer the question because it looks like a complete mess. Try learning coding from scratch.

Comment: @codingfreak ok I'll do it thanks for your help

Comment: @Reynier no problem :) w3schools.com might be a good start to begin with.

Comment: You said you coded it yourself, then you should know why finish button is never activated: there is nothing in your code that references `finish-wizard` button.

Comment: @Reynier - Looking at your test code, it appears that the `click` events for `#previous-step` and `#next-step` are virtually identical, with the only difference being whether the code uses `prev` or `next` and `next-step` handing `step_count == 4`. So i'm wondering why 1) you don't combine the two and simply swap out `prev` or `next` based on the target event trigger element and 2) do you mean to have `step_count == 4` not handled by `prev`?